# create drag and drop sortable list with angular5 and ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng2-dragula

I've got most of my app working and the last part is to show a list of items the user can rearrange in different order and save it in that new order. I've been developing using angular5 (cli) and ng-bootstrap.

How do I create such list? I see it's possible with ngx-bootstrap
(https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable)
 but I would really rather not change now that I'm almost done. Is there a way to accomplish this using ng-bootstrap?

*Edit to add example data*

The data have this kind of structure (array of objects):

```
data = [
  {name: 'adam',id: 'asedf'}, 
  {name: 'brian', id: 'aeqww'}, 
  {name: 'carl', id: '34534'}
]
```

Called from the html like

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of data; let i=index;">{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And I want the user to be able to rearrange the list of names and have it reflected in the underlying data model.

Comment: Can you post an sample of the list and on which basis you want to rearrange in different order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally did was to skip ng-bootstrap and use Dragula.

The HTML template:

```
<ul [dragula]='"thebag"' [dragulaModel]="data">
  <li *ngFor="let person of data">person.name</li>
</ul>
```

The component:

```
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any[];

constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
  dragulaService.setOptions('thebag', {});
  dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe((value) => {
    this.onDropModel(value);
  })
  this.data = [];
}
private onDropModel(args: any): void {
  const [el, target, source] = args;
  console.log('onDropModel:');
  console.log(el);
  console.log(target);
  console.log(source);
}

save() {
  console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sort to achieve this :

```
dataToSort = [
    { name: 'dadam', id: 'asedf' },
    { name: 'brian', id: 'aeqww' },
    { name: 'catl', id: '34534' },
    { name: 'carl', id: '34534' }
  ]

this.dataToSort.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
```

### BeforeSort :

[image]

### AfterSort

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you're right that I can sort the list, but the *user* needs to be able to drag and drop to reorder the list, with the reordering bound to the data model. hence the angular/bootstrap query.